# На главной отображать, на всех остальных скрыть!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ребята, подскажите каким образом сайд бар отображать на главной странице, а когда переходишь на товар или другую страницу что бы он прятался!?

Comment: Хочу на остальных страницах выводить сайд бар при клике на кнопку в хедере, но пока застрял на том что не могу спрятать на всех сраницах кроме главной!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> каким образом сайд бар отображать на главной странице, а когда переходишь на товар или другую страницу что бы он прятался?

JS - вараинт.

```js
var path = window.location.pathname;
var page = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
console.log(path, page);
if(page === "home-page.html"){
   // Show sidebar
}
else if(page !== "home-page.html"){
   //Hide sidebar
} else{
  // Anything else
}
```

- *widow.location.path* - URL содержащий `/`
- *substring* - возвращает подстроку от 0 и до последнего индекса `/` + 1

Comment: А как на других страницах сделать так что бы при нажатии на кнопку в хедере скрытый сайд бар появлялся ?

Comment: у меня на Вордпрессе тема Диви, так на page.php я хотел body задать другой id , да там все через <? php не нашел куда id задать

Comment: Поместить в файл, который подгружается на всех старницах.

Comment: На главной сайд бар у меня показывает, перехожу на товар или другую страницу его там нету, вот морочусь как сделать так что бы при нажатии на кропку в хедере выпрыгивал этот сайд бар, мне что в хедер добавить html сайд бара ??

Comment: Добавлю в хедер сайд бар, block: none и через клик актив класса сделать что бы показывался ?

Comment: Тогда нужно сделать что бы эта кнопка в хедере которая показывает сайд бар на других страницах не работала на главной!! Помогите пожалуйста!!

Comment: Как это внедрить изходя из, того что у вас есть (в вордпресс)  это другой вопрос. Задайте отдельно.